# What does these errors mean in riak install?

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, riak

Missing plugins: `[rebar_lock_deps_plugin]`?

> ERROR: OTP release 18 does not match required regex R16|17?

I have installed and running erlang and otp v17:
`[{release,"Erlang/OTP","17","6.4",...`

I have OpenSSl installed (1.0.1f)

I did install all other required dependencies needed to install riak.

Cant seem to find solution to this. Please Help!!

Comment: This means that somehow you're running Erlang/OTP 18, while Riak supports only versions 16 and 17. `which erl` should tell you what Erlang installation is first in the path.

Comment: with that i get /usr/local/bin/erl

Comment: is there a way to check which version that is?

Comment: If you run it from the shell without arguments, it should say something like `Erlang/OTP 17` in the first line of output.

Comment: no, i only get that path. could that indicate some kind of problem in erlang install?

Comment: Running it means running `/usr/local/bin/erl`, that will give you a shell and print the version as legoscia pointed out

Answer (score 3):

The problem resides in `riak/rebar.config` file. There is a regex comparing the OTP with R16, but it seems that after OTP 17 the "R" character got discarded.

Editing `rebar.config` before `make rel` is enough.

Tested with `riak-2.0.6`

Answer (score 1):

I changed it to

{require_otp_vsn, "R16|17|21"}.

But another failure

> Compiling /Users/yuanwen/git/riak-2.2.3/deps/cluster_info/src/cluster_info_basic.erl failed:
>   /Users/yuanwen/git/riak-2.2.3/deps/cluster_info/src/cluster_info_basic.erl:81: erlang:get_stacktrace/0: deprecated; use the new try/catch syntax for retrieving the stack backtrace
>   /Users/yuanwen/git/riak-2.2.3/deps/cluster_info/src/cluster_info_basic.erl:171: erlang:get_stacktrace/0: deprecated; use the new try/catch syntax for retrieving the stack backtrace

occured!

So still need to install Erlang/OTP 17 instead of the latest version